# Access to ios simulator from runing docker container

Tags: docker, react-native, ionic-framework, expo

In Ionic or Expo(react-native) when youre developing your app you can run with android/ios simulator.

So in case of working on my local os it works perfectly! :)

However,If I want to develop my app via docker container, I could simply setup node env with ionic/expo cli globally installed.

So, is it possible to execute expo/ionic in simulator mode(i.e ionic run ios) inside docker but opening the xcode ios simulator on the local/host mac os?